# where is receive method in akka.actor.Actor trait

Tags: scala, akka

Where is `receive` method is declared in  `akka.actor.Actor` trait ?
I tried to see the scaladocs http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/actor/Actor.html ,but didnot find there ,What am I missing ?

Comment: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/Actor.scala#L471

Comment: Not everyone is going to dig the source code specially beginners ,my question is why it is not in documentation

Comment: It should also be noted that version 2.0 is ANCIENT (or even pre-historic) ;-) Please replace "2.0" with "current" to see the current stable version’s documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a `protected` method and the page only shows `public` methods by default. Switch "Visibility" to "all".

Comment: Oh, I also need to learn how to read scala docs BTW thanks a lot